# Variable of Variable in Python

Tags: python

I've a list of variable names, how can I print value of it using for loop..

```
var1="First"
var2="Second"
list=["var1","var2"]
for var in list:
   print(var) # I want to print value of var,
```

present output
var1
var2

What I want is

```
First
Second
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Do some basic research using search engines.

Comment: User a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
list=["var1","var2"]
```

You've made a list of strings, not variable names. What you need is

```
list=[var1,var2]
```